# Issue converting returned string with decimal to number for calculation

Tags: php, jquery

I am scraping from a remote site div using simple_dom in PHP
and then the page containing the script is then called using AJAX

The issue I have is I need the numbers that are returned from the scrape
contain a lot of decimal places and its being treated as a string.
I then need to run a calculation on that returned data.

I have included all relevant code below.

Example  :
The scrape returns 0.000000000000423 as a string ( it contains a $ sign so I use str_replace to remove the $ )
I then need to convert the value to a number and then do a calculation which is the value * 1000000000000

However I usually get NaN

Here is the code

Scraping Page :

```
require('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
   $page = file_get_html('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tsuki-inu/');
$price = $page->find('div.priceValue___11gHJ', 0);

    $showprice = str_replace('$','',$price);
    echo $showprice;
```

jQuery on main page that calls the scrape page via ajax

```
<script>
function calcfdmc(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'fdmc.php',
  type: 'get',
  success: function(fdmc){
  fdmcval = parseFloat(fdmc);
  converted = fdmcval * 1000000000000000;
  console.log(converted);
      $("#fdmc").html(converted);
  },
  complete:function(fdmc){
   setTimeout(calcfdmc,2000);
  }
 });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(calcfdmc,2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tested your code and I never receive NaN. Is it possible that sometimes your `PHP` isn't able to scrape the remote address and therefore is unable to provide the actual price? Please check your console log for when you receive NaN and check the value returned by PHP

Comment: The scrape does work and pulls a live price with 12 decimal places
At present the scrape returns $0.0000000434
This is before the str_replace to remove the $ sign

Comment: before `fdmcval = parseFloat(fdmc);` add `alert(fdmc);` or console log to see what is actually returned by php

Comment: I have updated the actual url above to teh one im using for the scrape
Also the alert returns <div class="priceValue___11gHJ">0.0000000437</div>

Comment: @ChrisYates so, here is you problem, you're returning html code instead of pure number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple HTML DOM Parser: how to read the value of the selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129630/simple-html-dom-parser-how-to-read-the-value-of-the-selected-option) or [PHP Simple HTML DOM - How to get the text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371302/php-simple-html-dom-how-to-get-the-text-inside-a-tag)

Comment: I suppose you need to replace `$price = $page->find('div.priceValue___11gHJ', 0);` with `$price = $page->find('div.priceValue___11gHJ', 0)->innertext;`

Comment: Found the mistake .. I wasnt striping out the div element ..
Working fine now :)

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones yep, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to strip out the DIV element
Was fixed by :

```
$price = $page->find('div.priceValue___11gHJ', 0); with $price = $page->find('div.priceValue___11gHJ', 0)->innertext;
```